# Swapping elements based on index given from another list

Tags: list, prolog

Hello my task is to swap elements of list, with the index that needs to be swapped in another list, so fx:

If I have:

```
[3,1,2] as the list
```

And:

```
[[1,2],[2,3]] as the index that needs to be swapped
```

Then it should go like:

```
[1,2] = 3 and 1 getting swapped
[2,3] = 3 and 2 getting swapped
```

So i would end up with Output = [1,2,3]

The predicate is specified to be like this:

```
swap(C,Input,Output)
```

Where C is the list of which elemenst that should be swapped.

Input is the list that should be swapped.

Output is the swapped list.

I would like some advice on how to swapping those elements based on this, I have already looked at this: [swap two elements from list with specified indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26834387/swap-two-elements-from-list-with-specified-indices)

Hope that someone can help me with this.

Edit:

So far I have tried something like this:

```
swap( Input,[I|J], Input ) :-
    I = J.
swap( Input, [I|J], Output ) :-
    swap( Input, [I|J], Output, _, _ ).
swap( Input, [I|J], Output ) :-
    swap( Input, J, I, Output, _, _ ).

swap( [E2|Ls], I,  0,  [E1|Ls], E1, E2 ):-!.
swap( [E1|Es], 0, J, [E2|Rs], E1, E2 ) :-
    N2 is J - 1,
    swap( Es, -1, N2, Rs, E1, E2 ),!.
swap( [E|Es], [I|J], [E|Rs], E1, E2 ) :-
    N1 is I - 1,
    N2 is J - 1,
    swap( Es, N1, N2, Rs, E1, E2 ).
```

But I am only able to use "one" list as the indexes of what that has to be swapped, like [1,2], what I am looking for is being able to use multiple like [[1,2],[2,3]] and so on.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Post edited with what I have tried now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list_i_j_swapped/4

```
list_i_j_swapped(As,I,J,Cs) :-
 same_length(As,Cs),
 append(BeforeI,[AtI|PastI],As),
 append(BeforeI,[AtJ|PastI],Bs),
 append(BeforeJ,[AtJ|PastJ],Bs),
 append(BeforeJ,[AtI|PastJ],Cs),
 length(BeforeI,I),
 length(BeforeJ,J).

swap(List,[],List).
swap(List1,Swaps,ListSwapped):-
  Swaps =[[Index1,Index2]|T],
  list_i_j_swapped(List1,Index1,Index2,List2),
  swap(List2,T,ListSwapped).
```

Q:

```
?- swap([3,1,2],[[0,1],[1,2]],X).
X = [1, 2, 3] ;
false.
```

The positions are zero indexed.

Comment: s(X): how about doing a variant based on [tag:meta-predicate] `foldl/4` (as a separate answer if you choose)?

Comment: I am not sure how foldl would work for this? I only understand it for something like summing a list. I would be interested in seeing how it would work for swap/3.

Comment: Got it? Sure! Also note that `foldl/4` can also be used with [tag:dcg]s as `foldl//2`.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on [this previous answer by @user27815](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33376104/4609915).

Here comes the [lambda](/questions/tagged/lambda) + [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) variant!

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

swap2(Ls0, Swaps, Ls) :-
   foldl(\[I,J]^S0^S^list_i_j_swapped(S0,I,J,S), Swaps, Ls0,Ls).
```

Sample query:

```
?- swap2([3,1,2], [[0,1],[1,2]], Xs).
  X = [1,2,3]
; false.
```